# is JAXRS resource can use for different requests?

Tags: jax-rs

I am using JAXRS to communicate between two application using http request.
During implementation I had an argue with my college, who said I can't use the same resource (org.apache.wink.client.Resource) for different request, as it can cause collision.

I argue that such thing can't happen, and by using the same resource for all requests, I am improving performance.

Bellow is a code snippet, please help to resolve our dispute

```
public class jaxrsDeliveryService{

    private Resource queryResource;

    public void init(){
        servletPath = url + REMOVE_COUNT_SUFFIX_URL;
        queryResource = restClient.resource(servletPath);
        queryResource.contentType(APPLICATION_XML).accept(APPLICATION_XML);`
    }

    public QueryResponse getqueryResult(QueryInfoRequest qir){
        ClientResponse response = resource.put(qir);
        return response.getEntity(QueryResponse.class);          
    }
}
```

Comment: What jax-rs implementation are you guys using ?

Comment: They are using [Apache Wink](http://incubator.apache.org/wink/), I suppose

Comment: Is this client or server side?

Answer (score 0):

[`Resource`](http://incubator.apache.org/wink/1.0/api/org/apache/wink/client/Resource.html) is an interface that says nothing about thread-safety. Thus, we should assume that its implementation may be unsafe. If you want to make your class thread-safe you 1) should not use the same `Resource`, or 2) put its use into `synchronized` block.

If you don't worry about thread safety, reuse the `resource`. You will gain a little performance.